# Android NumberPicker with Formatter doesn't format on first rendering

Tags: android, formatter, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I have a NumberPicker that has a formatter that formats the displayed numbers either when the NumberPicker spins or when a value is entered manually. This works fine, but when the NumberPicker is first shown and I initialize it with `setValue(0)` the 0 does not get formatted (it should display as "-" instead of 0). As soon as I spin the NumberPicker from that point on everything works.

How can I force the NumberPicker to format always - Both on first rendering and also when I enter a number manually with the keyboard?

This is my formatter

```
public class PickerFormatter implements Formatter {

 private String mSingle;
 private String mMultiple;

 public PickerFormatter(String single, String multiple) {
    mSingle = single;
    mMultiple = multiple;
 }

 @Override
 public String format(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return "-";
    }
    if (num == 1) {
        return num + " " + mSingle;
    }
    return num + " " + mMultiple;
 }

}
```

I add my formatter to the picker with `setFormatter()`, this is all I do to the picker.

```
    picker.setMaxValue(max);
    picker.setMinValue(min);
    picker.setFormatter(new PickerFormatter(single, multiple));
    picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(wrap);
```

Comment: Could you post some code, it helps in answering.

Comment: its just a standard implementation, really:

Comment: added some code, but the code is not the issue, the numberpicker just doesnt execute the code on first render

Comment: im a bit new to this but can you call format() from the constructor function? I don't think it is called initially. Would that help?

Comment: I've just googled it and found this issue report on the Android project: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35482 Let's wait for a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin version based on [Nikolai's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54083214/534471) answer

```
private fun initNumberPicker() {
    nrPicker.children.iterator().forEach {
        if (it is EditText) it.filters = arrayOfNulls(0)    // remove default input filter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

[dgel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19104078/332528) doesn't work for me: when I tap on the picker, formatting disappears again. This bug is caused by input filter set on `EditText` inside `NumberPicker` when `setDisplayValues` isn't used. So I came up with this workaround:

```
Field f = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mInputText");
f.setAccessible(true);
EditText inputText = (EditText)f.get(mPicker);
inputText.setFilters(new InputFilter[0]);
```

Comment: Worked for me on API 25. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

I also encountered this annoying little [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35482).  Used a technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15475635) to come up with a nasty but effective fix.

```
NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker)view.findViewById(id.picker);
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(5);
picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
picker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(int value) {
        return my_formatter(value);
    }
});

try {
    Method method = picker.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("changeValueByOne", boolean.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(picker, true);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Calling that private `changeValueByOne` method immediately after instantiating my number picker seems to kick the formatter enough to behave how it should. The number picker comes up nice and clean with the first value formatted correctly.  Like I said, nasty but effective.

Comment: Somehow in Android programming you have to use nasty hacks very often.

Comment: can't believe, that this is not yet fixed.

Comment: this bug was reported 2 years ago... are you kidding me google? still an issue on android 4.4.2

Comment: Doesn't work for me: whenever I tap on the picker, formatting disappears again. I came up with another [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797732/332528)

Comment: Indeed - this is still present in Marshmallow :(

Comment: Still not fixed, but the method changeValueByOne() is missing in newer SDKs, so this exact solution no longer works. :-/

Comment: Today 11th Nov 2016 Still issue exists :-(

Comment: It's nice to have some good guys saving you a lot of trouble like this=)

Comment: Android 7.1.1 and the bug seems to be completely unnoticed still.

Comment: Elon Musk launched a  tesla into the space and this issue still exists.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and I used the `setDisplayedValues()` method instead.

```
int max = 99;
String[] values = new String[99];
values[0] = “-” + mSingle
values[1] = 
for(int i=2; i<=max; i++){
    makeNames[i] = String.valueOf(i) + mMultiple;
}
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(max);
picker.setDisplayedValues(values)
```

This doesn't allow the user to set the value manually in the picker though.

Comment: From the [Android Developer Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html): Note: The length of the displayed values array set via setDisplayedValues(String[]) must be equal to the range of selectable numbers which is equal to getMaxValue() - getMinValue() + 1.

Answer (score 7):

The following solution worked out for me for APIs 18-26 **without using reflection**, and without using `setDisplayedValues()`.

It consists of two steps:

1. Make sure the first element shows by setting it's visibility to invisible (I used Layout Inspector to see the difference with when it shows, it's not logical but `View.INVISIBLE` actually makes the view visible).

   ```
   private void initNumberPicker() {
    // Inflate or create your BugFixNumberPicker class
    // Do your initialization on bugFixNumberPicker...

    bugFixNumberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
       @Override
       public String format(final int value) {
           // Format to your needs
           return aFormatMethod(value);
       }
    });

    // Fix for bug in Android Picker where the first element is not shown
    View firstItem = bugFixNumberPicker.getChildAt(0);
     if (firstItem != null) {
       firstItem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Subclass NumberPicker and make sure no click events go through so the glitch where picker elements disapear on touch can't happen.

   ```
   public class BugFixNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    public BugFixNumberPicker(Context context) {
       super(context);
    }

    public BugFixNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BugFixNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performLongClick() {
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       return false;
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution based on answers by [torvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26797732/3185295) and [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949069/3185295). You don't have to subclass anything or use reflection.

```
View editView = numberPicker.getChildAt(0);

if (editView instanceof EditText) {
    // Remove default input filter
    ((EditText) editView).setFilters(new InputFilter[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution this worked for me using databindings, a numberpicker and a formatter also including unicode signs.

Answer (score 4):

Calling the private method `changeValueByOne()` via reflection as described in an earlier answer works for me on `API Level 16` (Android 4.1.2 and up), but it does not seem to help on `API Level 15` (Android 4.0.3), however!

What works for me on API Level 15 (and up) is to use your own custom formatter to create String array and pass that with the method `setDisplayedValues()` to the number picker.

See also: [Android 3.x and 4.x NumberPicker Example](https://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/)

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by NoActivity worked for me but I only had to do:

```
View firstItem = bugFixNumberPicker.getChildAt(0);
if (firstItem != null) {
  firstItem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

to fix the issue.  I did not need to subclass NumberPicker.  I did not see the issue where picker elements disappear on touch.

Comment: I can confirm the formatted elements disappear on touch (tested on Lollipop).

Comment: This is the best working answer, (for me) the accepted one works as well, but using with compose , the text color disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by calling

```
picker.invalidate();
```

just after setting the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Improved Nikolai answer if selected index is not 0. Not to great for performances but fix the problem..

```
for(index in numberPicker.minValue..numberPicker.maxValue) {

        val editView = numberPicker.getChildAt(index-numberPicker.minValue)
        if (editView != null && editView is EditText) {
            // Remove default input filter
            (editView as EditText).filters = arrayOfNulls(0)
        }
    }
```