# What is an Alternative to the UIPickerView from IOS in android?

Tags: java, android, ios, spinner, uipickerview

I am trying to reproduce the IOS UIPickerView functionality but in android.

[image]

In IOS you can set this UIPickerView as an input type of the keyboard. I need this same type of interaction but in android.

UPDATE:
When I say input type I mean the UIPickerView simply replaces the keyboard view. So if a textfield were clicked the UIPickerView would open instead of the Keyboard. Hope that clears stuff up!

Comment: you dont set input view here.. you can just open up a dialogfragment with timepicker.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. However can I populate the time picker with different values other than time? For example I want to store feet on the left and inches on the right. Is that possible with the TimePickerDialog?

Comment: you probably need to use spinners here

Answer (score 2):

not sure exactly what you mean by

> as an inputtype of the keyboard

but the android equivalent to that image would be the [TimePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html)

**Update**

If you want that picker type of UI you have 3 options for pickers, the TimePicker, DatePicker or the [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) obviously the first 2 are out so you are left with the `NumberPicker` with the number picker you can populate it with the numbers you want (inches) and then another for feet

I suggest you take a quicl look at the Pickers article
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a layout with multiple pickers, that way you can have as many as you need and initialise them with any values you require.

The below layout will give you two spinners side by side similar to the iOS UIPickerView.

I've posted a link to my github repo at the bottom with a simple example showing how to use 3 spinners, one for minutes, hours and days that should help you (Or anyone else coming from iOS with the same question) can use as a base to get started.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/multispinner">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[My simple multiple picker example](https://github.com/spik3r/Multispinner)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number picker, if you're looking for a similar feel. Just make sure to add a personalized style as theme (or else it will take your app theme as default) and add a formatter to the number picker. You'll run into some trouble on the first render (it won't show the first value until you scroll), just use the solution provided here: 
[Android NumberPicker with Formatter doesn't format on first rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708325/android-numberpicker-with-formatter-doesnt-format-on-first-rendering/44949069)

You can also put it into a cardview like in the image, it looks tidy enough. 
[formatted number picker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0WwG.png)

Ps.: Actually you can modify several fields, but you have to acces the class fields/methods. To do so, do as this exmaple code.

```
public void setNumberPickerDivider (NumberPicker picker) {
    Field[] fields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field f:fields){
        if(f.getName().equals("mSelectionDividerHeight")){
            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                f.set(picker,1);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```