# Formatted value of NumberPicker disappears onClick

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, dialog-preference, android-number-picker

My NumberPicker in `setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` mode and the `setWrapSelectorWheel(false)` is turned off.

I formatted my Numberpicker with a simple formatter:

```
mNumberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(int value) {
        return TextUtils.makeQuatityString(getContext(), value, R.plurals.nWeek);
    }
});
```

Example output: 4 Weeks, where 4 is the value.

The NumberPicker is in a Dialog and after a short click on the value, the "Weeks" disappear, the "4" stays. Now, after a longer click, the formatted text re-appears.

Does anybody now how to fix this?

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: No sorry, i didn't find a solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NumberPicker with Formatter does not format on first rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708325/android-numberpicker-with-formatter-does-not-format-on-first-rendering)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35482) 
Others are facing this issue too. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708325/android-numberpicker-with-formatter-does-not-format-on-first-rendering).

This worked for me. I tested at API 24.

```
      try {
            Field f = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mInputText");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            EditText inputText = (EditText) f.get(yourPicker);
            inputText.setFilters(new InputFilter[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```