# The value of NumberPicker doesn't change

Tags: kotlin, android-widget, android-number-picker

I'm a beginner in android and Kotlin.
I want to get string values I set as displayedValues from NumberPicker.
I tried, but It only returns Int numbers.

After some search, I found a question  [Formatted value of NumberPicker disappears onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458566/formatted-value-of-numberpicker-disappears-onclick) which might be the solution to my problem.

But I'm beginner and never studied java, so I couldn't apply it to my code. I need your help to figure out whether my code is correct and if it is, I hope to get a solution which can be applied to kotlin
Thankyou!

```
    val pickers = arrayListOf(picker1,picker2,picker3,picker4,picker5,picker6,picker7)
    for (picker in pickers) {
        picker.displayedValues = arrayOf(
            "0", "30", "40", "50", "60", "1시간", "1시간 30분", "2시간", "2시간 30분", "3시간", "3시간 30분", "4시간",
            "4시간 30분", "5시간"
        )
        picker.minValue = 0
        picker.maxValue = 13
        picker.setFormatter { num -> picker.displayedValues[num] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation of the answer there to Kotlin is

```
// do this outside the loop because it doesn't depend on picker
val f = NumberPicker::class.java.getDeclaredField("mInputText")
f.setAccessible(true)

// inside the loop
val inputText = f.get(picker) as EditText
inputText.setFilters(arrayOf())
```

(it's surrounded by `try-catch` which you can do in Kotlin as well if you want but the particular `catch` there is useless; and if you do it should be outside the `for` loop).

Comment: I checked my question and your answer after wake up and I figured out that the link I posted is a totally different question. Of course, the answer couldn't solve my problem. it seems that since I was so tired, I made this mistake. I'm sorry and thank you.

Comment: I decide not to get the string value directly, but to handle the Int value in other way